API run well for generating JWT Token into \auth URL BUT always returns ERROR : 401 Invalid credentials
Try to create API project with latest stack SF7, APIPlatform 4 and JWT.
API run well for generating JWT Token into \auth URL
BUT always return me ERROR : 401 Invalid credentials
lot of trying solution into web and stackOverflow but nothing resolve this.
Perhaps issue or mistake with the particular stack...
Advice for you are appreciate
These requirements is done :

generating JWT key

activate JWT lexik bundle into bundles.php

getUserIdentifier() set to User Entity


security.yaml
security:
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

providers:
    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\Users
            property: email

firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
        security: false

    main:
        stateless: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        json_login:
            check_path: auth
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        jwt: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/docs, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:

secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(resolve:JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'

routes/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /api

routes.yaml
auth:
  path: /auth
  methods: ['POST']

controllers:
    resource:
        path: ../src/Controller/
        namespace: App\Controller
    type: attribute

UserFixtures.php :
    $user1 = new Users();
    $user1->setCivility('mr');
    $user1->setEmail('toto@toto.com');
    $user1->setRoles(['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN']);
    $hashedPassword = $this->hasher->hashPassword($user1, 'rere-toto');
    $user1->setPassword($hashedPassword);
    $user1->setUsername('jordy');
    $user1->setFirstName('michael');
    $user1->setLastName('jordan');

    $manager->persist($user1);
    $manager->flush();

Users.php (Entity)
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UsersRepository::class)]
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(name: 'UNIQ_IDENTIFIER_EMAIL', fields: ['email'])]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account with this email')]
#[ApiResource]
class Users implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private bool $isVerified = false;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $civility;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $firstName;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $lastName;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string')]
    private string $username;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'blob', nullable: true)]
    private string $picture;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 2)]
    private string $locale = 'fr';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): static
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCivility(): string
    {
        return $this->civility;
    }

    public function setCivility(string $civility): void
    {
        $this->civility = $civility;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): void
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName(): string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): void
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return $this->username;
//      return $this->email;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): void
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getLocale(): string
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }

    public function setLocale(string $locale): void
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getIsVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): static
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPicture(): string
    {
        return $this->picture;
    }

    public function setPicture(string $picture): void
    {
        $this->picture = $picture;
    }
}

.env
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=a0b919dGJxxxxxxcaa29fkh56bxxxxx2fde41f13381b7dac864


The issue dealing with the verification of the login.
Lexik bundle (3.0) remove the 'user_identity_field' options into it's config file. Then it provide verification between username (and with new version you can't change that) and email (configured with api platform and security symfony engine).
If you downgrade the lexik package with the number 2 version you can retrieve the 'user_identity_field' option and can set that with 'email' value.
After that all run correctly.
